# Spring data jpa extend Jsr310JpaConverters

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring boot and i have a problem with a jsr310 date conversion.
In my entity i have a ZonedDateTime and in my db a Timestamp.
I try to extend Jsr310JpaConverters class and to add this converter

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
    public static class ZonedDateTimeConverter implements     AttributeConverter<ZonedDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(final ZonedDateTime locDateTime) {

        return (locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.from(locDateTime.toInstant()));
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(final Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return (sqlTimestamp == null ? null : ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(sqlTimestamp.toInstant(), TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId()));
    }

}
```

but when i try to get an entity from db i have this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.time.ZonedDateTime field it.advansys.gestionalebdf.common.BaseEntity.creationdate to java.sql.Timestamp
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:38)
```

i also add this on my Application.class

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = "my.package.entity", basePackageClasses = MyCustomConverter.class)
```

can someone help me?
thanks

edit:
the entity property where i have problem is this.

```
@CreatedDate
@Column(name = "`CREATIONDATE`", updatable = false, nullable = false)
@Type(type = "java.sql.Timestamp")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@NotNull
private ZonedDateTime creationdate;
```

Comment: Please also post the date property from your entity class.

Comment: I added the property. thanks